# Existence of Hyponitrite Molecule

Tags: bond, molecules

Does the hyponitrite molecule exist? I know the hyponitrite ion exists (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponitrite) but what about the molecule?

I have found no reference to the molecular form on Wikipedia. But it does seem that such a molecule could at least come together through the dimerization of nitric oxide.

Comment: Apparently, $\ce{NO}$ does indeed dimerize at low temperature. Plenty of references come up in a search, and this is mentioned on the Wikipedia page for nitric oxide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see [Structural and Stablity of Nitric Oxide Dimer](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00755a006).

Just don't call it "hyponitrite molecule", it might get offended.