# Nitrogen dioxide dimerization

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, molecules, energy

$\ce{NO}$ can't dimerize and that is explained because the free electron is in an antibonding orbital. The same is true for $\ce{NO2}$, but it can dimerize, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an electron in an antibonding orbital means that the electron exists in a high energy orbital.  If anything, this means the electron will be "motivated" to react and form a bond, particularly if bond formation lowers the energy of the electron.  An electron in an antibonding orbital can form a bonding (as opposed to antibonding) bond with positive overlap.

Comment: Why doesn't oxygen for a dimer then?

Comment: Good question!  Remember that NO only dimerizes at low temperatures.  Apparently molecular oxygen does similar things.  Since molecular oxygen has 2 unpaired electrons, maybe we would expect a polymer or a cyclic oligomer?  It turns out that one form of solid oxygen actually exists as $\ce{O_8}$.  Read about "red oxygen" or $\ce{O_8}$ in this Wikipedia article  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen#Red_oxygen  Here's a link to an article where $\ce{O_4}$ is reported  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-3773(20011105)40:21%3C4062::AID-ANIE4062%3E3.0.CO;2-X/abstract

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that nitric oxide can't dimerize? It has a rather high bond order - 2.5 - and we can see that from molecular orbital theory. Therefore even if its free electron is in an antibonding orbital, that wouldn't decrease the bond order to 0 or below.

The nitric oxide dimer has actually been extensively studied too.

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00381a052

Comment: How can it dimerize if antibonding electrons residue in HOMO?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/13537/5084

Comment: I don't think that hyponitrite is the same as a NO dimer.